# Can I use different map type with intents

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent

I am new to Android and need some clarifications.

I want to switch to different map types (Roadmap, satellite, hybrid) when using `ACTION_VIEW` intent in my application.

Is it possible? I don't find any map type data in the URI on Android developer site.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. These are Map types:

- **Normal**
- **Hybrid**
- **Satellite**
- **None**

> To set the type of a map, call the GoogleMap object's setMapType()
>   method, passing one of the type constants defined in GoogleMap. For
>   example, to display a satellite map:

```
GoogleMap map;
...
// Sets the map type to be "hybrid"
map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
```

There is a API information about your question
[Google Maps Android API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/map)

Answer (score 0):

use radio buttons or checkboxes for(normal,satellite,hybrid), based on your choice(click event) map shows (normal,satellite,hybrid) map types.check below code

```
GoogleMap googleMap;
googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
```